# How to access directly and efficiently on very large text file?

Tags: c++, c, file-io, mpi

I have a very large text files (+10GB) which i want to read for some data mining technics. 
To do that, i use parallel technics with MPI so many processes can access together to the same file.
In fact, i want that each process read N number of lines. Since the file is not structured (same number of fields but each field can contain different number of characters), i'm in the obligation to parse the file and that is not parallel and it takes a lot of time.
Is there any way to access directly to a specific number of line withount parsing and counting the lines? 
Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If your file isn't otherwise indexed, there is no direct way.

Indexing it might be worth it (scan it once to find all the line endings, and store the offsets of each line or chunk of lines). If you need to process the file multiple times, and it does not change, the cost of indexing it could be offset by the ease of using the index for further runs.

Otherwise, if you don't need all the jobs to have *exactly* the same number of lines/items, you could just fudge it.
Seek to a given offset (say 1G), and look for the closest line separator. Repeat at offset 2G, etc. until you've found enough break points.

You can then fire off your parallel tasks on each of the chunks you've identified.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i think that the second idea is better since i normally parse the file on time. So considering this soluion, i will make each process access from a specific offset lets say (File_size/process_number *process_rank) then i look for the beginning of a new line.  So i would loose at worse number_of_process lines?

Comment: +1 Scanning once to find line breaks and handing the indices to other processes is absolutely preferrable to anything else, because any random seeks will be several orders of magnitude more expensive than anything you can buy from parallelizing the parsing of some fields per line in a text file. Sequential reads and pulling from the buffer cache are fast, everything else defeats every optimization.

Comment: @ezzakrem: if you can afford not to parse certain lines, I guess you could do that. But I wouldn't. Before you start spawning off workers, in your main "thread", you find all the break points you need. The you give begin/end offsets to each of the workers before you start them.

Comment: @MAT: that's not a problem since my data minig algorithm ignore already certains lines. Otherwise, Does fseek() parse file before accessing to the specified offet? i means it's an O(n) or O(1)? if it's an O(1) i will parse once file (i can use that also to have more informations about data before starting datamining it will help me to be more precise in prediction), get break point then launch workers. 
i just hope that fseek() is O(1).

Comment: `fseek` seeks completely blindly. It moves the file pointer by the specified number of bytes, that is all. Whether that's exactly constant time or not could depends on the file system implementation details, but given your scenario that won't matter - the seek will be "instantaneous"). (Unless your file is on a mechanical tape drive...)

Comment: that's a good news! that's what i'm willing to do! thank you for this bright idea.

Comment: @Damon What makes you think that random seeks are expensive?

Comment: Note that if the solution involves random seeks, you'll have to open the file in binary mode (and use a platform dependent definition of the line terminator).  If the file is opened in text mode, the only seeks which are legal are to the front, the end, or to a position returned by `tell`.

Comment: If you define a convention with regards to how you find the start and the end of your sequence, you don't need to search for the line breaks in the parent process; each thread can search for its own start and finish.  Depending on the system, it may be an advantage for each thread to do its own open (separate buffers, etc.).

Comment: so if i get offsets in binary mode, i will not be able to parse the lines in text mode? 
Even if i make each thread/process search for its own start using fseek() i would not be able to read text data?

Comment: @JamesKanze: Well, what makes you think seeks are not expensive? Even on a SSD, small random reads perform much worse than a single large, continuous one, let's even not think of mechanical disks with rotating platters and moving heads. If you could prefault whole file into the buffer cache, things would be different, but obviously that isn't possible or the question would not make sense in the first place. While you wait for the disk, nothing happens in your worker process. Even if you fire off 10,000 processes (in a manner like a GPU works) then only 1-2 at a time will get ready.

Comment: @ezzakrem: if it matters at all on your platform, open in binary mode to find the breaks, open in text mode to do the processing.

Comment: @Damon: the "fudge it" approach I suggest only makes sense if you're going to delineate _large_ chunks. Obviously if you try to do that with 2 lines per block, the overhead is going to be as heavy as the full indexing.

Comment: @Mat: You're right, I wonder inhowfar parsing something like "lines with same number of fields" (i.e. something like CSV?) benefits from parallelization anyway, unless you hand each process, say, a hundred or so lines minimum. Passing a single line through IPC probably takes longer than parsing it in the first place... but I guess the OP knows and thought about that. Either way, my point is that hitting several millisecond delays from disk access (kind of impossible to avoid with seeking) would be a total killer. Milliseconds are an eternity in CPU terms. So I'd really try...

Comment: ... to avoid this e.g. by scanning over the file in one thread linearly (and hopefully the worker processes are fast enough so you keep the working set in buffers all the time, with only the "scanner" ever blocking, if at all).

Comment: @Damon Experience.  It's clear that reading the same amount of data randomly will be significantly slower than reading sequentially, but reading a few odd blocks will be significantly faster than reading the whole file.

Comment: You could memory map the file and let the OS/FS figure out the best caching and seeking approach to use (presuming that is optimized in the OS/FS).

Comment: I think that chunking the file into blocs of 10 000 lines is faster than reading the whole file by a bloking process. Since there is a way to fseek() directly into blocs that will certainly increase performance. 
I'm speeking about one day or more of processing time. Few milliseconds delays it's not really a problem since i can cover that by making other thread processing data from the first line until the first break point. In addition, may i need some time before other worker start to read a new bloc? Because many blocs of 10 000 lines will saturate the RAM.

Answer (score 10):

A few other options beyond what has been mentioned here that will not require scanning the whole file:

1. make a master process that pushes lines via pipes/fifos to child processes that do the actual processing. This might be a bit slower but if say 90% of the time spent in the subprocesses is the actual crunching of texts, it should be ok.
2. A stupid but effective trick: say you have N processes, and you can tell each process by argv or something it's "serial number" e.g. `processor -serial_number [1|2|3...N] -num_procs N`, they can all read the same data, but process only lines that have  `lineno % num_procs == serial_number`. it's a bit less efficient because they will all read the entire data, but again, if they only work on every Nth line, and that is what consumes most of the time, you should be fine.

Comment: +1 for alternative thinking. Sometimes the best way to win, is to change the rules.

Answer (score 4):

No there isn't: until you don't read through your unknown data nobody will know how many new line characters there are. This problem complexity is O(n) thus meaning that *at least once* you'll have to read the whole file. Then you might want to build an index table where you record where there are new line characters in your file: this can be used by all process and with fseek you can speed up dramatically further access.

Comment: thank you for response, it seems a good solution. I will do that and see if it worths since in serial mode, i read one the file, then for each line i do many CPU computing. So far i have two solutions : i parse file to construct an index file then all processes can use it. Or i make one process read from file and make other processes doing calculations.

Comment: With O(n) I referred to this notation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Linear_time
By the way, indexing is very easy to be executed paralel. If you have several processes, you can split up the file _also for indexing_, so let's say the 1st process reads through the 1st Gb, the 2nd the 2nd, etc. and all save the positions of the new line characters into the same shared resource. This can speed up also the indexing. Don't forget however that depending on the storage hardware you use, sequential reading might be MUCH faster.

Comment: so it's about mixing two steps
1- make N processes getting indexes as you said.
2- for cpu computing, each process access directly with fseek() to the specific offset. 
That looks nice to try.
Thank you